# How to install Linux on Pendrive without using existing EFI partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, grub, uefi

I am using live Mint Linux to make a full install of Linux on a pendrive, which works fine; however, during installation, the EFI partition of the main hard drive of the PC is modified.

Is it possible to make full Linux install on a pendrive in such way that GRUB is installed only on the pendrive without using the PC's SSD, as I want to make full install on a pendrive with the boot process independent of any other device *(similar to live Linux)*?

I have following partition setup:
[image: partition setup]

with following installation setup:
[image: installation setup]

but when I check file systems just after installation starts I can see that EFI(def/sdb1) is not used but the partition of the main PC drive is used
[image: df -hT]

This is relevant log after the installation is started:

```
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/sdb1
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint 05efi: debug: /dev/sdb1 is a FAT partition (mounted by GRUB)
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint 05efi: debug: /dev/sdb1 partition scheme is dos
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint 05efi: debug: /dev/sdb1 partition type is 0xef
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint 05efi: debug: /dev/sdb1 is not a ESP partition: exiting
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint 10freedos: debug: /dev/sdb1 is a FAT partition (mounted by GRUB)
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint 10qnx: debug: /dev/sdb1 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint macosx-prober: debug: /dev/sdb1 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint 30utility: debug: /dev/sdb1 is a FAT partition (mounted by GRUB)
Mar 31 18:07:17 mint 83haiku: debug: /dev/sdb1 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
Mar 31 18:07:18 mint ubiquity[2678]: Device /dev/sdb1 not found in os-prober output
```

It appears to be problem with Ubiquity and the the scripts located under /usr/lib/os-probes/

Comment: You may need to manually create an EFI partition on the pendrive, as the default is to use the existing EFI partition since only one should exist - if this still results in the hard drive's EFI partition being modified, the Linux Mint man pages should have a section on how to force it to use the EFI partition on the pendrive. Often a live install will use a different partitioning scheme and/or filesystem since a Live USB is intended to be run from RAM versus a normal install is intended to be run from the drive.

Comment: Could You provide more details? I wasn't able to find relevant information on mint homepage: https://linuxmint.com/documentation.php

Comment: Choosing _Something Else_ \[[#5](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-linux-mint-on-the-computer)\] and manually creating the requisite partitions [EFI, `/`, etc.] doesn't result in the installer using the EFI partition created?

Comment: You would need to create three partitions: EFI, root [`/`], swap [equal to RAM size]. The installer should use the EFI partition created, however if not, once installed, follow the [EFI troubleshooting](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/efi.html#) steps or use a search engine to determine how to create the EFI boot files _(I don't use Linux Mint and am looking at the same documentation you are)_

Comment: Yes, but during installation EFI partition does not need to have mount point specified, right?

Comment: That's correct - the only mount point you'd specifiy is `/` _(as well as `/home` if using a separate partition for it)_

Comment: I have followed yours instructions but there is still a problem...

Comment: It does need a mount point, because you're going to have to put files on it...

Comment: After setting "EFI System Partition" it does not show mount point on it but it remembers the setting. I have added system logs after the installation is running